# Query optimization to split all authorized pairs values in two columns with defaults

Tags: oracle

I would like to optimize oracle query to transform table with all authorized pair values in two columns. The first with exceptions of authorized by default and the second exceptions of forbidden by default.

For example :

```
| ROOM  | USER AUTHORIZED |
| ROOM1 |   A             |
| ROOM2 |   A             |
| ROOM2 |   B             |
| ROOM3 |   B             |
| ROOM4 |   B             | 
| ROOM5 |   B             | 
| ROOM2 |   C             |
| ROOM3 |   C             |
| ROOM4 |   C             |
```

To:

```
ROOM | USER EXCEPTION AUTHORIZED | USER EXCEPTION FORBIDDEN |

ROOM1|          A                |       B;C
ROOM2|          A                |       
ROOM3|                           |
ROOM4|                           |
ROOM5|                           |       C
```

I used this query to get exception forbidden:

```
WITH USERS
        AS( SELECT USER FROM ROOM_USERS GROUP BY USER HAVING count(*)>(SELECT count(*)/2 FROM ROOM_USERS )),
    ROOMS
        AS( SELECT DISTINCT(ROOM) as room FROM ROOM_USERS)
SELECT ROOM, LISTAGG(USER, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY USER)
FROM USERS, ROOMS
WHERE USERS.user||ROOMS.room NOT IN (
    SELECT user||room
    FROM ROOMS_USERS
)
GROUP BY room;
```

Comment: When you say "optimize" what do you have in mind? faster execution time?

Comment: From your sample:`ROOM2|          A                |       B`, how do you know A is authorized and B is not?

Comment: Because for A is less expensive to considered A all forbidden by default except ROOM1 and ROOM2 and for B is less expensive to considered B all authorized by default except ROOM1.
Edit: Sorry, it's an error for ROOM2.